# restriction of a relative sheaf on a section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

suppose $X\rightarrow Y$ is a projective bundle, with a section $s$.

Is the relative tangent bundle $T_{X/Y}$ free when restricted to the section $s$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s : Y \to X$ be a section of *any* morphism $X \to Y$. Since $s$ is a monomorphism, we have $Y \times_X Y = Y$. Then we have

$$s^* T_{X/Y} = T_{Y \times_X X ~/~ Y \times_X Y} = T_{Y ~/~ Y \times_X Y} = T_{Y  ~/~ Y} = \mathcal{O}_Y.$$

Comment: Iam bit confused; suppose the relative dimension is $r$. Then the pullback $s^*T_{X/Y}$ is of rank $r$.